# Dependency Injection engine in PHP

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I am writing a PHP Dependency Injection engine in PHP could you guys direct me to some valuable documents/articles which I can read?

I know I have a very generic question:
I have read these articles:

> 1] http://www.potstuck.com/2009/01/08/php-dependency-injection/
>   2] http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection
>   3] http://www.slideshare.net/fabpot/dependency-injection-with-php-and-php-53
>   4] http://ralphschindler.com/2011/05/18/learning-about-dependency-injection-and-php
>   5] http://loosecouplings.blogspot.com/2011/01/dependency-injection-using-di-container.html
>   6] http://www.pbell.com/index.cfm/2006/11/19/How-to-Write-your-own-Dependency-Injection-Engine
>   7] http://miller.limethinking.co.uk/2011/07/07/dependency-injection-moving-from-basics-to-container/

I still am not able to get a proper footing on the subject.

`final edit:`
Thanks to Gordon for pointing this link out : [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) 
Which I had missed to bookmark! Available at the end of this article: [what-is-dependency-injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection)

I think I have a good understanding of the concept now. Will be starting off with the code. Thanks to all who commented here

Comment: What about? I'm reading a number of interesting articles right now, for example one on the Gridlock in american politics, and another on the War on Drugs. Should I forward you the URLs? :)

Comment: Seriously though, you need to add *some* detail on what it is what you want to learn / need more information about...

Comment: Removed the MVC tag, because DICs have nothing to do with MVC.

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/PICO/IoC+Types and http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: ref: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection and [this](http://twittee.org/) ;)

Comment: @yoshi I have read the fabien article will go through it again. Thanks for the other link.

Comment: @Pekka have added some more details. :)

Comment: +1 for actual research effort. But the question scope is still way too broad. Join the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) tomorrow. They like such OO topics there IIRC.